# Cleaning Messy Scraped Table Data Rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am relatively new to pandas and python. I am trying to cleaning up some scraped PDF data read into a data frame that isn't isn't correctly parsed. where a few of the single row in the source PDF table is split into three rows like below:

| index | Item | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | some string that is split... | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | NaN | 4 | 20 |
| 2 | ... rest of string | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | some string that parsed as it should | 1 | 22 |
| 4 | another string that is split... | NaN | NaN |
| 5 | NaN | 3 | 121 |
| 6 | ... rest of the other string | NaN | NaN |
| 7 | 3rd string that is split... | NaN | NaN |
| 8 | NaN | 15 | 5 |
| 9 | ... rest of the 3rd string | NaN | NaN |

When ever there is this pattern I basically need to merge the three lines into one line.

so the desired output is

| index | Item | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | some string that is split... ... rest of string | 4 | 20 |
| 3 | some string that parsed as it should | 1 | 22 |
| 4 | another string that is split... ... rest of the other string | 3 | 121 |
| 7 | 3rd string that is split... ...rest of the 3rd string | 15 | 5 |

What would be the best way to do this?

what I have done so far is very clumsy and feels quite wrong even though it sometime works on some of the scraped data. It just can't trust it.

```
# Get the rows that have NaN in the quantity column
split_rows = df[df['Quantity'].isna()]

# every other line where 'Total' is NaN needs to be removed later, but not before the dtata is copied        
rows_to_remove = split_rows.iloc[1::2,:].index
        
# 
__i = 0
while __i < len(split_rows):
   df.at[split_rows.index[__i],'Quantity'] = df.at[split_rows.index[__i]+1,'Quantity']
   df.at[split_rows.index[__i],'Price'] = df.at[split_rows.index[__i]+1,'Price']
   df.at[split_rows.index[__i],'Item'] =  str(df.at[split_rows.index[__i],'Item']) + " " + str(df.at[split_rows.index[__i]+2,'Item'])
    __i += 1 
        

# remove the rows like row 3
df = df.drop(rows_to_remove, axis=0)

# drops rows like row 2    
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Is there a better way to do this. What would be the canonical way to approach something like this?

much obliged

EDIT:

made a table of the desired output, made the input more like the ones I am dealing with. clarified the question.

Comment: What is the defining factor that the string is split into three?

Comment: Please can you update your post with more samples and set the expected output?

Comment: @Tofusoul answered you.

Comment: Now, we need you had more rows of your input dataframe

Comment: Much better now :)

Comment: @onyambu, added the desired output, which is also what the source pdf table kind of looks like. so the pdf scraping has kind of split a single line into 3 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a bit tricky. First, create a boolean match to exclude right rows. Next, with this mask create virtual groups of bad rows then reindex the output with the original index of your dataframe and use interpolate to create new groups for good rows. The rest is pretty standard: group rows the aggregate data:

```
m = df.isna().any(axis=1)
g = df.loc[m, 'Item'].isna().cumsum().shift(-1).ffill().reindex(df.index).interpolate()

out = (df.fillna({'Item': ' '}).groupby(g, as_index=False)
         .agg({'Item': ''.join, 'Quantity': max, 'Price': max}))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                                                           Item  Quantity  Price
0               some string that is split... ... rest of string       4.0   20.0
1                          some string that parsed as it should       1.0   22.0
2  another string that is split... ... rest of the other string       3.0  121.0
3        3rd string that is split... ... rest of the 3rd string      15.0    5.0

>>> g
0    1.0  # bad rows, group 1
1    1.0  # bad rows, group 1
2    1.0  # bad rows, group 1
3    1.5  # good row, group 1.5 due to interpolation
4    2.0  # bad rows, group 2
5    2.0  # bad rows, group 2
6    2.0  # bad rows, group 2
7    3.0  # bad rows, group 3
8    3.0  # bad rows, group 3
9    3.0  # bad rows, group 3
Name: Item, dtype: float64
```

Comment: sorry for being a total noob but if the "Quantiy' and 'Price' columns are strings instead of numbers and NaNs proper (so string 'nan'), how would the grouping df be generated? This will really help with understanding what's going on with the solution too and how to generally approach dealing with data in pandas too. much obliged!

Comment: You just have to prepare the data before create the mask and groups. `df = df.replace('nan', np.NaN)`. The rest is still the same. Don't forget to include numpy: `import numpy as np`

Answer (score 0):

Index is set before grouping df.set_index('index'). A function 'func_data' is created to process the values.
First, the values of 'np.nan' are checked by the isin function. Next, values are extracted where there are no empty values and all columns are converted to string so that it is possible to combine all values into one line in 'join'.

```
def func_data(x):
    ind = x.isin([np.nan])
    a = x.values[~ind]
    a = a.astype(str)
    return (" ".join(a))


df = df.set_index('index')

df['new'] = df.groupby(['index'])[['Item','Quantity', 'Price']].apply(func_data)
df = df.reset_index('index')
print(df)
```

Output

```
   index                          Item  ...  Price                           new
0      1  some string that is split...  ...    NaN  some string that is split...
1      2                           NaN  ...   20.0                      4.0 20.0
2      3            ... rest of string  ...    NaN            ... rest of string
```

Comment: sorry for the unclear question, and thanks for taking the time to help. the source table should read as the output (in the edited question) but is parsed instead into 3 lines. I am trying to merge them into 1 line like the output. the index was in there to show that they are in that order.